Do I need a new blower fan/motor?
Had the AC running and noticed the furnace started making an unusually loud noise. When I opened the panel it appears the noise is coming from the blower fan. When I spin the fan manually, it spins freely without any rubbing or grinding. What will need to be replaced and are there any good DIY step by step YouTube videos to follow?
Don’t know how to link a video so I’m sharing a link to a Reddit post I created looking for answers there:
https://www.reddit.com/r/hvacadvice/s/r4wm3SQJN9

It's possible that the fan just needs to be cleaned. With the high speed the fans spin at, a bit of dirt on one of the blades could cause it to be unbalanced when you get to a higher speed.

If you end up having to replace the fan motor and can swing it, consider an Electronically Commutative Motor (ECM) as a replacement. If you run your fan continuously, you can save enough on your electricity bill to pay for it in 10 months.

@DelphicOracle interesting, haven’t thought of that. Will definitely look into it, thanks for the tip!
